# Vapor - Create a room session with ID

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

I'm working on a Vapor backend and I'm looking to create sessions for single entry. The client should ask to create the session and the backend will return a session ID that the client can use.
This is the outline:

```
// routes.swift

func routes(_ app: App) throws {
    app.post("create_room") { req -> BaseResponse<CreateRoomResponse> in
        let roomName = try req.content.decode(CreateRoomRequest.self).name
        let roomId = "ABCD"
        
        // Create a session, store credentials...
        ...

        return CreateRoomResponse(status: .ok, payload: roomId)
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out where to store the session data and ID for later use, and potentially destruction after `x` amount of time.
I've read in the Vapor documentation about both Authorization and Sessions but couldn't quite found something that fits my needs, or at least not in a way I can intuitively implement as my experience with backend programming is not great.
How would I go about to implement a session like this? Where do I store the credentials and how do I access them later down the way?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I store data in the session data dictionary. Usually, this persists until the end of the session, as you would expect. However, I also use a piece of custom middleware that logs a session out after a specified period. Would this do what you need?

Comment: @Nick Yes, It's exactly what I need. I managed to figure out how to store the data in `session.data`, but I would really appreciate it if you could show me an example of how you would destroy the session after a specified period with a custom middleware as you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should destroy the session and any data you have stored in `session.data`. If it is the first request in a session then the initialisation of `lastRequestTimeStamp` fails and defaults to the current time. It then stores the current time in `session.data`. If the request is more than 20 minutes since the last one, it logs the user out (which destroys the session) and re-directs to "/".

```swift
 struct SessionTimeoutMiddleware: Middleware {
     func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
         let lastRequestTimeStamp = Double(request.session.data["lastRequest"] ?? "BAD") ?? Date().timeIntervalSince1970
         request.session.data[C.Dict.Key.LastRequest] = String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
         if Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - lastRequestTimeStamp > 1200 { 
             request.auth.logout(User.self)
             return request.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(request.redirect(to: "/"))
         }
         return next.respond(to: request)
     }
 }
```

And, finally, register the middleware in `configure.swift`.

`app.middleware.use(InternalErrorMiddleware())`